# How to get connection string from another project in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I've 3 different projects in one solution. I placed my connection string in first project like this

```
 <connectionString name="My Connection String">
     <parameters>
     <parameter name="Integrated Security" value="True" />
     <parameter name="server" value=".\SQLEXPRESS" isSensitive="true" />
     <parameter name="database" value="MyDatabase" isSensitive="false" />
     </parameters>
  </connectionString>
```

Now in another project I make LINQ to SQL class and it generated app.config file and make it's connection string in it? How can I make to read connection string from my exisiting .config file from another project?

Comment: you want to get the connection string of one project from another project? You just have to expose it via some class/property

Comment: Can you explain it? I want to change my LINQ to SQL class's connection string  to read it from another project's connection string.

Comment: is that `connectionString` setted in a `web.config` or an `app.config` file inside your solution?

Comment: It's in project's `web.config` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Application Settings and have a connection string in your **FirstProject**.

Like this:

[image]

The generated Settings class is marked  `internal sealed partial ..` so you can't directly access it via `MyProject.Properties.Settings..`.

You just create a class to expose it:

```
namespace FirstProject
{
    public class ThisProjectSettings
    {
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return Settings.Default.Conn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it from your **second** project like this:

```
FirstProject.ThisProjectSettings.ConnectionString
```

Comment: I've thought about this. But in this case, I don't want to add first project's reference to second. I don't think it correct, because first is Backend, and second is UI. They might be independent. So is any better way, to make it more generic. For example, make connection string file for all projects.

Comment: So the UI is not dependant on the backend in any way? You could roll out your own configuration storage mechanism but you should figure out if you really need to do that.